# Synonyms for Sankt and St

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to get synonyms working for my existing setup. Currently I have this settings:

```
PUT city
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_synonym_filter",
                        "german_normalization",
                        "my_ascii_folding"
                    ]
                },
                "autocomplete_search": {
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_synonym_filter",
                        "german_normalization",
                        "my_ascii_folding"
                    ]
                }
            },
                  "filter": {
                     "my_ascii_folding": {
                     "type": "asciifolding",
                     "preserve_original": true
            },
                  "my_synonym_filter": {
                  "type": "synonym",
                  "ignore_case": "true",
                  "synonyms": [
                     "sankt, st => sankt"
                  ]
            }
          },
            "tokenizer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 15,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "symbol"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "city": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this `City` Index I have documents like that:

`St. Wolfgang` or `Sankt Wolfgang` and so on. For me `St.` and `Sankt` are synonyms. So if I search for `Sankt` both of the documents should appear.

I created a new Filter and added the filter to my `autocomplete analyzer`:

```
"my_synonym_filter": {
   "type": "synonym",
    "ignore_case": "true",
    "synonyms": [
        "sankt, st."
    ]
}
```

So good for now. But the issues I faced are following:

Its clear that the dot after `st` is not analyzed and not searchable at the moment. But For the synonym the dot is important.

The second issue is if I search for `sankt` the synonym is `st` which gives me all documents which starts with st like `Stuttgart`. So this happens also because the dot is not used.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve the stuff? If you need any more information, please let me know.

---

**Update:**

After discussions I did this changes in my settings:

changed `edge_ngram` tokenizer to a `standard` tokenizer.

added an `edgeNGram` filter and added this filter to my analyzer.

deleted the filter `german_normalization` and `my_ascii_folding` from my analyzer to simplify the tests.

```
PUT city
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter",
            "edge_filter"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "my_synonym_filter",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "edge_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        },
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "synonyms": [
            "sankt, st => sankt"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "city": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added these 3 documents to the index:

```
"name":"Sankt Wolfgang",
"name":"Stuttgart",
"name":"St. Wolfgang"
```

---

Query String - Result

```
st      ->    "St. Wolfgang", "Stuttgart"
st.     ->    "St. Wolfgang", "Sankt Wolfgang"
sankt   ->    "St. Wolfgang", "Sankt Wolfgang"
```

Comment: Can you try changing your synonyms with `sankt, st. => sankt`, i.e. `st.` will be indexed as `sankt` so searching for `sankt` will return `sankt` and searching for `st.` should also only match `sankt`. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @Val I dont get any document by changing the synonyms. Thats strange. Do you have any other idea to get this working?

Comment: Can you update your settings with the synonym token filter so I can reproduce this on my end?

Comment: Oh, you actually need to add the synonym token filter also in your search-time analyzer, so that someone typing `st.` also searches for `sankt` under the hood.

Comment: @Val I edited the settings. Its exactly what I use. And yes I added the synonym filter to the search_analyzer. If you need also data for indexing or anything else, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm you probably need to add it after the lowercase filter otherwise it won't work, moreover I don't see it in the definitions of filters.

Comment: And `asciifolding` after `german_normalization` is probably redundant too

Comment: @Val updated again. I will check your oppinions also by my own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167811/discussion-between-patrick-and-val).

Comment: Again, `my_synonym_filter` should be after `lowercase` in the `filter` list of your analyzer, otherwise the synonyms won't match

Comment: @Val yeah I tried it out. I think I got some point now. So after set `my_synonym_filter` after `lowercase` and this `"sankt, st => sankt"` rule I got all 3 documents back for the query of `sankt`.: `St. Wolfgang`, `Sankt Wolfgang` and `Stuttgart`. So I changed the synonym rule to `"sankt, st. => sankt"` becuase `stuttgart` should not be in the result. But now I just get `Sankt Wolfgang` as a result. `st. wolfgang` is not comming because the dot is not analyzed.

Comment: The problem is that at indexing time the synonym filter is after the edge-ngram tokenizer and hence the `st` token from `Stuttgart` (a 2-gram from the tokenizer) will also go through the synonym matching. The only way I see to solve this is to use a standard tokenizer and use the edge-ngram token filter instead of tokenizer

Comment: @Val thanks for your help. I just tried it but unfortunately `stuttgart` is  in the result when I use the rule with the dot `"sankt, st. => sankt"` Is there a way to make the dot analyzeable?

Comment: Where did you place the edge-ngram token filter in the list?

Comment: this it the filter `"edge_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        },` and I set it as last member

Comment: My question was where did you place it in your analyzer filter list?

Comment: at last member. after `"my_synonym_filter",
            "lowercase",`

Comment: At this point I think you should add an "UPDATE" section in your question and post exactly what you have, otherwise we're running in circles, thanks

Comment: @Val I updated the question.

Comment: Well, `my_synonym_filter` is still not after `lowercase`...

Comment: And you should not use the edgeNGram filter at search time, only at indexing time, like in your original example.

Comment: yeah my mistake. changed the order now. the result looks better now. The query `sankt` gives the correct results.  In Query `st`  I miss `stuttgart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works pretty well for me. The main point here is to make sure to

- put the synonym filter after the lowercase one
- put the edge-n-gram filter at the end
- use the edge-n-gram only at indexing time

So we create the index:

```
PUT city
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter",
            "edge_filter"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "edge_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        },
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "synonyms": [
            "sankt, st. => sankt"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "city": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we index data:

```
PUT city/city/1
{
  "name":"St. Wolfgang"
}
PUT city/city/2
{
  "name":"Stuttgart"
}
PUT city/city/3
{
  "name":"Sankt Wolfgang"
}
```

Finally searching for either `st` or `sankt` will only return documents 1 and 3 but not 2

```
POST city/_search?q=name:st
POST city/_search?q=name:sankt
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I copied your index. But for me `sankt` gives me just doc 1 and 3 when I change the synonym to `"sankt, st => sankt"` (without dot).  And for query `st` `stuttgart` should also be a match. for `st.` `stuttgart` is not an option anymore.

Comment: Let's take this upside down. Can you formulate for each search input, what output you'd like to have?

Comment: sure. I updated my question with the query string and the result.

Comment: Can you try the `whitespace` tokenized instead of the `standard` one?

Comment: just for the analyzer at index time? or also the search_analyzer?

Comment: I'd try both just to see

Comment: It looks quite good. I will check that with a set of more documents.

Comment: the result of the large set of documents is also quite good. Just to make sure that I use the right synonym rule. I use now (based on the query/result update) this rule `"sankt, st. => sankt, st."` Is this correct?

Comment: You can make it simpler with `"sankt, st."` without arrow, which boils down to saying that both tokens are completely equivalent

Comment: Thank you so much. Works pretty well!

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out!